# como fazer uma barra de progresso que vá de 0 a 70 e não volte do inicio?

Tags: javascript, html, css3, animação, keyframes

Preciso de uma barra que vá de 0 a 70% e que não volte a 0 apos chegar nos 70, não pode recomeçar o ciclo, tem que parar quando chegar no numero maximo.~

```
@keyframes site {
    from { width: 0 }
    to { width: 73% }
}

.siteload {
    background: #E7E7E7;
    position: relative;
    height: 25px;
    width: 80%;
    left: 45px;

    border-radius: 6px;
}

.siteload::after {
    border-radius: 6px;
    animation: site 5s infinite ease-in-out;
    background: rgba(247,170,88,1);
    content: '73%';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;

}
```

Comment: Tire o `infinite` da `animation. Isso é o que faz com que repita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que faz com que repita é o [animation-iteration-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) que ficou a `infinite`:

```
animation: site 5s infinite ease-in-out;
/*                    ^---- este       */
```

Esse indica quantas vezes a animação repete, sendo que `infinite`, como o próprio nome indica, repete infinitamente.

Apesar disso, mesmo sem o `infinite` a animação irá voltar ao estado inicial após terminar. Para modificar este comportamento pode colocar [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) como `forwards`, que mantem as propriedades aplicadas pela animação.

Combinando estas duas alterações a propriedade `animation` deve ficar assim:

```
animation: site 5s ease-in-out forwards;
```

Veja o seu exemplo a funcionar com essa alteração:

```css
@keyframes site {
    from { width: 0 }
    to { width: 73% }
}

.siteload {
    background: #E7E7E7;
    position: relative;
    height: 25px;
    width: 80%;
    left: 45px;

    border-radius: 6px;
}

.siteload::after {
    border-radius: 6px;
    animation: site 5s ease-in-out forwards; /* linha alterada */
    background: rgba(247,170,88,1);
    content: '73%';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="siteload"></div>
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!